# Server response throwing Unable to process while uploading document/Photo to server in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, file-upload, multipartform-data, document

I am trying to uploading document to server. In Action sheet, User can choose Photo from gallery to Document to upload.

So, I am taking either photo or document and converting it into Data.
After that I am sending that data to server along with two parameters (keys, values) with multipart.

But, Unfortunately I am getting error like **Unable to process** from server, But same thing working in Android domain.

Here is my code:

```
    func uploadDocument(documentId:Int, data: Data, filePath: String, categoryType: String, completion: @escaping uploadDocumentClosure) {
        
        let url = "https://somedomain.com/uploadDocument"
        
        let requestURL = URL(string: url)!
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: requestURL)
        request.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
        request.httpShouldHandleCookies = false
        request.timeoutInterval = 30
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        let filename = "avatar.png"
        // generate boundary string using a unique per-app string
        let boundary = UUID().uuidString

        let docData = data
        
             let idStr = "id"
            let docTypeStr = "documentType"
            let file = "file"
        
        var data = Data()

        request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("Bearer \(accessToken ?? "")", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        
        data.append("\r\n--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)

        data.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(docTypeStr)\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
        data.append("\(categoryType)".data(using: .utf8)!)

        data.append("\r\n--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
        data.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(file)\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)

        // Add the image data to the raw http request data
        data.append("\r\n--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
//        data.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
//
        if let dataa = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filename)\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n".data(using: .utf8) {
            data.append(dataa)
        }

        data.append("Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
        data.append(docData)

        data.append("\r\n--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
        
        self.serviceManager.async(request: request as URLRequest) { (innerClosure) in
            do {
                let response = try innerClosure()
                guard let json = response.jsonObject else {
                    completion({ throw JSONErrorType.parsingError })
                    return
                }
                let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: [])
                let responseModel = try JSONDecoder().decode(EditProfilePhotoUploadResponse.self, from: jsonData)
                completion({ return responseModel })
            } catch {
                completion({ throw error })
            }
        }
    }
```

And the sever response is below

```
{
  "status" : "E",
  "message" : "Unable to process.",
  "data" : null,
  "messageList" : null
}
```

With status code 400 bad request.
In Android they simply sending below code and its working fine.

```
@Multipart
@POST("somedomain.com/uploadDocument")
suspend fun uploadDocument(
    @Part file: MultipartBody.Part,
    @Query("documentType") documentType: String
): GenericMessageResponse
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your server doesn't like what you are sending. In order to get any useful answers you need to post the _working_ request that can be compared to what Swift code is sending.

Comment: I have added android code which is working, Pls check once

Comment: I dont really understand why some people suggest to close the query even they are not able to give solution. This is really irritates. If we really stuck some where in the code after try with some solution which did not work, we used raise query here to get some useful suggestion or help to us.

Comment: You need to post a question in the way people can take your code, try it out (e.g. in Playground or empty project) and reproduce the problem you encounter. Without that the question is unanswerable. And no, android code is not helpful either.

Comment: I have fixed the issue by myself. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much debugging, I have fixed the issue with below solution.

I used below library

```
https://github.com/Fyrts/Multipart.git
```

Here my code changes are below

```
    func uploadDocument(imageData: Data, filePath: String, fileName: String, categoryType: String, completion: @escaping uploadDocumentClosure) {
        
        let url = "https://wwww.somedomain.com/uploadDocument"
        let requestURL = URL(string: url)!
                    
        let imageeData = ImageData(name: fileName, filePath: filePath, imagedata: imageData)
        
        let string = imageeData.filePath
        
        let mimeType = string.mimeType() //here list of mimes we can get from predefined
        
        let fileContents = try! Data(contentsOf: URL(string: filePath)!)
        
        var message = Multipart(type: .formData)
        message.append(Part.FormData(name: "documentType", value: "\(categoryType)"))
        message.append(Part.FormData(name: "file", fileData: fileContents, fileName: "\(imageeData.name)", contentType: "\(mimeType)"))
        
        var URLrequest = URLRequest(url: requestURL)
        URLrequest.httpMethod = "POST"
        URLrequest.setMultipartBody(message)
        URLrequest.addValue("/(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        
        self.serviceManager.async(request: URLrequest as URLRequest) { (innerClosure) in
            do {
                let response = try innerClosure()
                guard let json = response.jsonObject else {
                    completion({ throw JSONErrorType.parsingError })
                    return
                }
                let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: [])
                let responseModel = try JSONDecoder().decode(EditProfilePhotoUploadResponse.self, from: jsonData)
                completion({ return responseModel })
            } catch {
                completion({ throw error })
            }
        }
    }
```